# Facebook is asking me app-ads.txt for login sdk, and it is not working

Tags: react-native, facebook, app-ads.txt

I have a react native app with admob, my app-ads.txt is present and validated by Google. The app is in PlayStore, everything works fine.

I added Facebook login button for the new version, I created the app on Facebook developer dashboard, but there is a section in general settings that asks me to confirm the ownership by adding a line to my app-ads.txt. If I don't pass this step, I can't put the Facebook app in live mode.

Even if I don't understand why I have to do it since I do not advertise on Facebook with this app, I added each of theses lines, and tested them one by one, and each time Facebook tells me that an error has occured and it can't proceed.

```
facebook.com,MY_FB_ADVERTISING_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT_ID,DIRECT,c3e20eee3f780d68
facebook.com,MY_FB_ADVERTISING_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID,RESELLER,c3e20eee3f780d68
facebook.com,MY_APP_FB_ID,RESELLER,c3e20eee3f780d68
facebook.com,MY_APP_FB_ID,DIRECT,c3e20eee3f780d68
```

Just to be sure that FB has the good url, I renamed the app-ads.txt file on my server, FB tells me that no valid file was found. So, there is no problem with the url or the developer website declared on the play store.

The problem is surely in the file content, and I can't be sure which line is good.
Does someone has an idea?

Details: The new version (with fb login button) is not in the playstore yet, there is only the fist one, does it matter?